# SceneBuilder how to remove style class?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I want to style a RadioButton as a normal button, but keep the RadioButton's functionality.

Instead of writing this in my code:

```
radioButton.getStyleClass().remove("radio-button");
radioBUtton.getStyleClass().add("toggle-button");
```

I want to do it in SceneBuilder. I'm aware that SceneBuilder has this section in the Inspector Panel:

[image]

But I only know how to add style-classes, not remove them. So it still has the RadioButton styling with the dot on the left. How can I do this in SceneBuilder, or, if I can't, can I include it in the CSS somehow? Or must I have it done in the code itself?

Comment: You definitely can't do it in SceneBuilder. You might be able to do it in FXML, with a bit of work. The easiest way is going to be using the code you posted in the controller.

Comment: Thank you, that was the exact answer I needed. I'm still learning all of this so I'm still having trouble with what is possible within SceneBuilder and what is not, and when to edit FXML vs Controller.

Comment: On a side note, are you sure you don't just want to use a `ToggleButton`? A `RadioButton` already **is** a `ToggleButton`, just with a different style. Therefore, it will already have all the same functionality.

Comment: I didn't know that. I actually got my previous idea from an older post so I assumed they had different functionalities. I'll look into it, I appreciate the input.

Comment: I agree with @Zephyr. Just note that `RadioButton` + `ToggleGroup` enforces that a `RadioButton` is always selected in the group (at least after the initial selection). That doesn't occur with `ToggleButton` + `ToggleGroup` out of the box—you'd have to implement it yourself. For `RadioButton` this is implemented [in the `fire` method](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/RadioButton.java#L109).

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely no way to accomplish your goal through Scene-Builder, since it was only developed in use as a UI Layout Tool. You can think of the manual adding and removing of a style class as a “preview” and current state of a class a node possesses but you cannot remove it again programmatically using the Builder.

The best way to solve this would be as you have already mentioned by applying this code into your controller-class:

```
radioButton.getStyleClass().remove("radio-button");
radioBUtton.getStyleClass().add("toggle-button");
```